# Unable to create Directory using CreateDirectoryW Function in WIN64

Tags: visual-c++

I am unable to create directory using CreateDirectoryW(). Kindly help me.

I am getting error, unable to create folder.CreateDirectoryW(L"c:\A\B,NULL ). but same code is working on 32machine

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post the relevant code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am getting error, unable to create folder.CreateDirectoryW(L"c:\\A\\B,NULL ). but same code is working on 32machine

Answer (score 1):

This won't work unless `c:\\A` already exists.  Check the error (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` ?). Does the user have permissions to write to that part of the disk?

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> One or more intermediate directories
>   do not exist; this function will only
>   create the final directory in the
>   path.

The code will operate the same on both machines, so this must be environment-specific.

In general all your Win32 API calls should check and handle errors.  That will speed up resolution of future issues like this.